# Office 365 import job PST Rest API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, pst

We have jobs to import PST files (attach screenshot) using office 365 admin portal,
i want to get job's status  [image]using Microsoft graph API it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non of the exchange online administration functionality is available in Microsoft Graph API at this time.

There are Exchange Online PowerShell commandlets that are available. have you checked there? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps

That team is starting to plan for this, with the intention then of being part of our Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK too.